# Scroll to top and refresh page at same time

Tags: javascript, html

ok, I have a code which smooth scrolls to the top of the page, but I also need it to reload (refresh) the page as well. Here is the code I have to scroll but I don't know how to implement the reload into it. Any thoughts most welcome.

```
var x = document.getElementById('title1');

function myFunction() {
   if (x.style.display === 'block') { 
       x.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
       x.style.display = 'block';
   }
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}
```

Comment: use location.reload(); on scroll top

Comment: Your chosen solution should keep UX in mind as to expected behavior. Slow scroll to top then reload produces a kind of bounce effect. Is that necessary for users to understand what the page is doing? Keep in mind on a slow connection, there could be a delay between the end of the scroll and the reload.

Comment: If any of the answers below answered your question please don't forget to **[mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or anyone else's) as correct, though marking a question as resolved helps keep things flowing smoothly :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, here is a simple solution. Jquery animate method provides us a callback method which run after animation finished, so you can try

var x = document.getElementById('title1');

```
function myFunction() {
   if (x.style.display === 'block') { 
       x.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
       x.style.display = 'block';
   }
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow", function(){
      window.location.reload()
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if scroll reaches top of page and refresh it by:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
      console.log('top');
      window.location.reload(false);
   }
});
```

`$(window).scroll(function(){
       if($(window).scrollTop() == 0){`
detect if window scroll reach top of page.

Refresh page: `window.location.reload(false);`

### Update:

To prevent detecting from manually scrolled you could add a flag whether it was manually scrolled or by animation: `var animate= false;` then you could update when `animate` was triggered: `animate=true;`

See snippet:

```js
var x = document.getElementById('title1');
var animate= false;

function myFunction() {
   if (x.style.display === 'block') { 
       x.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
       x.style.display = 'block';
   }
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
   animate=true;
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() == 0 && animate==true){
      console.log('top');
      window.location.reload(false);
   }
});
```

```css
body{
height:1000px;
}
#title1{
position:relative;
top:900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button id="title1" onclick="myFunction()">test</button>
</body>
```

Comment: That could be a bit annoying to the user when they scroll manually to the top and it suddenly reloads. Unexpected behavior.

Comment: Well true enough, I've added flag whether it was manual or animate call.

Answer (score 0):

you can reload using reload function in the Location class

```
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of the location.reload function as it will re-post the previous request if there is one. Browsers also try to be friendly and reload the page at the same scroll position, so you would have to scroll to the top, then reload.

A better bet is to use the location.search function. That will also give you the opportunity to pass extra parameters in the querystring to instruct the page to scroll to wherever you want.

Here's a handy js function you might find useful

```
/**
 * reloads a document without triggering the previous POST
 * @param {obj} document
 * @param {string} queryString optional overwrite of current qs
 */
function documentReload(document, queryString){
var loc = document.location;
//passing a queryString to container
if (queryString) {
    loc.search = queryString; //will cause it to reload
    return;
}
//refresh page
//loc.reload(true); - can cause the POST data warning
loc.href = loc.protocol +'//'+ loc.host + loc.pathname + loc.search;
}
```